# Searching for a more elegant (less code) way to compare multiple dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare

a while ago i asked a question about comparing 2 dicts to eachother, in order to detect same key's and keep the highest value of duplicates.
this community came with the a soltion which allowed me to compare 2 dicts to eachother and store the highest value of it in a new dict, which i can then compare to another dict if neccesary.

but as the number of dicts are getting higher, the code itself keeps getting larger.

```
for key in dict1:
    if key not in dict2 or dict1[key] > dict2[key]:
        dict2[key] = dict1[key]
dict2a = {**dict1, **dict2}

for key in dict2a:
    if key not in dict3 or dict2a[key] > dict3[key]:
         dict3[key] = dict2a[key]
dict3a = {**dict2a, **dict3}

for key in dict3a:
    if key not in dict4 or dict3a[key] > dict4[key]:
        dict4[key] = dict3a[key]
dict4a = {**dict3a, **dict4}
```

Im trying to come up with a solution that will iterate over all these dicts.
This question also hangs together with another question, but to keep solutions seperated, i ask this question in another help-question (how to open up multiple json txt files without getting errors and stops).
[Trying to get shorter way of opening multiple txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878199/trying-to-get-shorter-way-of-opening-multiple-txt-files)

In short, atm im creating a dict for each played contest, with playernames as key's and their scores a values.
This dict comparison is needed to filter playernames who attended to more then 1 contest, and to keep only their highest score. 
But perhaps another solution to this is to store all those different dicts in 1 big nested dict. That is at least the hint my teacher gave me. But i cannot find a way to compare nested dicts to eachother, and thus atm im bound to all these seperated dicts.

If any info is unclear please let me know so i can try to clearify it more.

thnx in advance

update:
an example of what is reached after a comparison:

```
dict1 = {"name1": 100, "name2": 20, "name4": 111}
dict2 = {"name4": 112, "name5": 23}

compared_dict = {"name1": 100, "name2": 20, "name4": 112, "name5": 23}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the two rules are:

1. Filter out duplicates
2. Include the score of the newest dictionary if it is greater than the old one

You are copying a lot of code... one of the first rules of coding best practices is DRY (don't repeat yourself!)

Let's define a method to merge our old and new dictionaries

```
def merge_dictionaries(old, new):
    changes = {}
    # keep the old one, don't edit the new one
    copy = old.copy()
    for player in new.keys():
        new_score = new[player]
        try:
            old_score = old[player]
        except KeyError:
            # if player doesn't exist in the old set, add them to the changes
            changes[player] = new_score
            continue
        if new_score > old_score:
            changes[player] = new_score
    copy.update(changes)
    return copy
```

The next step would be to iterate over a list of these dictionaries containing playernames and scores to total to a final result using the method above.

One solution may look like this:

```
def final_result(list_of_games):
    final = {}
    for results in list_of_games:
        final = merge_dictionaries(final, results)
    return final
```

A working example:

```
def merge_dictionaries(old, new):
    changes = {}
    # keep the old one, don't edit the new one
    copy = old.copy()
    for player in new.keys():
        new_score = new[player]
        try:
            old_score = old[player]
        except KeyError:
            # if player doesn't exist in the old set, add them to the changes
            changes[player] = new_score
            continue
        if new_score > old_score:
            changes[player] = new_score
    copy.update(changes)
    return copy

def final_result(list_of_games):
    final = {}
    for results in list_of_games:
        final = merge_dictionaries(final, results)
    return final

games = [
    {'kevin': 1, 'jack': 5},
    {'kevin': 2, 'blueberry': 1, 'jack': 3},
    {'kevin': 1, 'blueberry': 5, 'jack': 10}
    ]

print(final_result(games))
```

Which outputs

```
{'kevin': 2, 'jack': 10, 'blueberry': 5}
```

Comment: ive tried this and this works like a charm. so basically, what i need to do is not to put each contest into a different dict all by itself, but to put it in different dicts which are all in a big list. so if i do that, i only write (with json, see other question) 1 txt file, and read from only 1 txt file.

if i misunderstood the info above let me know.

ive just played a bit with this constructure, having multiple dicts in a list in a txt file, then read that list, and assign dicts to the items in the list. so that part is also working now.

Comment: You can keep each dictionary discrete, but then for processing purposes put them into a list to iterate over.  Sounds like you already got the hang of it though, I'm glad the above code is working well for you.  Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

The processing you've described doesn't sound like comparing dictionaries is required—it seems like you want to merge them together (and retaining only the highest score obtained by each player).

The `combine_dicts()` function below will accept any number of input dictionaries (collectively named `args` because of the `*` prefix.)

```
def combine_dicts(*args):
    combined = {}
    for arg in args:
        for player, score in arg.items():
            combined[player] = max(combined.get(player, 0), score)
    return combined

dict1 = {"name1": 100, "name2": 20, "name4": 111}
dict2 = {"name4": 112, "name5": 23}

result  = combine_dicts(dict1, dict2)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'name1': 100, 'name2': 20, 'name4': 112, 'name5': 23}
```

Comment: in our idea there are a total of 10 contests, in which players can attend to.
but when the same player takes part in more then 1 contest, his unique playername will be in several contest dicts. Big chance he reached different score in those contests. At the end im making a ranking list, and thus i only want to keep the highest score of this playername. Thats why i need to check if a playername is present more then once, and then compare his score (value) to only keep the highest score (value)

Comment: The `combine_dicts()` function can be passed any number of dictionaries as input arguments. 10 should be fine.

Comment: Its true that more then 2 dicts can be merged at the same time, but thats without keeping only the highest value in case of duplicate key's, as far as i understand it atm

Comment: Oh, OK, that's what you want. Still isn't really doing dictionary comparisons—see update.

Comment: you are right! im sry that i see this just now. ive tried your code with more then 2 dicts, and it also works like a charm.

Comment: arg and args is new for me, but what i understand from it is that you use the * so you can give unlimited number or args, and 'for arg in args' is very understandable. iterating over all the args.

Comment: darkrinoa: Hard for me to understand why you would prefer the much more involved code in the answer you accepted. Seems like the relatively simple approach I suggested is much more "elegant" (even though, as I said, it does not explicitly compare their contents). Hmmm, maybe that's why...

Comment: hi @martineau , th reason why is because there are 2 ways to compare dicts: 1 is to have each dict seperated like i previously did, and like your solution. your solution did make my code a lot shorter, but the solution to have all the dicts in 1 list, made a lot of other problems also disappear.
your code for just comparing is shorter, but it wasnt the best total solution for the other problems connected.

Comment: darkrinoa: I see, you selected the other answer because it addressed issues not mentioned in your question. That seems a little unfair to me...

Comment: im sry you feel that way, as it was never my intention not to mention related issues. i tried to( i believe i did) state as much as related issues, like the url i put in this question, pointing to another question related. but i do thnx you for your help, you all have helped me