# Trying to get shorter way of opening multiple text files

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get a better, cleaner, and short way to open multiple JSON coded text files. When all of these files exist, it's easy to put it inside one `try` code.

But when a file does not exist, the rest of the files won't be opened.
Also, each text file contains a dictionary and needs to be imported to a unique dictionary through `json.load`.

The code I have now is as follows:

```
dict1 = {}
while True:
    try:
        dict1 = json.load(open("temp/dict 1.txt"))
        break
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        break
    else:
        break

dict2 = {}
while True:
    try:
        dict2 = json.load(open("temp/dict 2.txt"))
        break
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        break
    else:
        break

dict3 = {}
while True:
    try:
        dict3 = json.load(open("temp/dict 3.txt"))
        break
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        break
    else:
        break
```

This question also hangs together with another question, asked in another topic:
[Searching for a more elegant (less code) way to compare multiple dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877373/searching-for-a-more-elegant-less-code-way-to-compare-multiple-dicts-in-python)

Perhaps there is another solution for both these problems I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were using break which would stop on first failure. What you should've done is to ignore the error and move on to the next file when the file didn't exist. I would also suggest you store your dictionaries in either an array or a dictionary referenced by the file name instead of as separate values. So your code would look something like this:

```
filenames = ['path1', 'path2']
loaded = {} 
for fp in filenames:
    try:
        with open(fp, 'r') as pointer:
            loaded[fp] = json.load(pointer)
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        continue
```

Comment: yes, in the other question (link in description) somebody else also came up with using dicts in a list. so basically now i have 2 ways to shorten my old way of open all the dicts.
1 = your solution (have to fully test it yet, but i do believe you know it works)
2 = putting all the dicts inside 1 list, and thus only dump and load from 1 txt file. the load part of this and assigning to unique dicts again i already have under control now